# Runtime Error Error in :0:0 caused by: No provider for StatusBar

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am building my ionic 2 app, and i get this error:

```
Runtime Error
Error in :0:0 caused by: No provider for StatusBar!
```

in app.component.ts, I have :

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
...
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

    pageComponent: any;
    private admobid: any;

    constructor(
          public platform: Platform
        , public statusBar: StatusBar
        ...
```

I don't understand if I have to list all the native plugins in the app.module.ts ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error suggests, you don't have a provider for StatusBar.

Add a provider either in your component,

```
@Component({
   .....
   providers: [StatusBar]
})
```

or preferably, in your NgModule

```
@NgModule({
   imports: ...
    .......,
   providers: [StatusBar]
})
```

In the latter case, you'll have to add another es6 'import' statement to allow the StatusBar type to be available to be added as a provider in the NgModule

Comment: Ok, I was not sure I add to also import and add them all in @NgModule.
thanks

Comment: It's a common problem i'm seeing recurring here - the confusion around es6/typescript import statements (the lines at the top of each typescript file) vs NgModule imports. For every ts file, you have to import into that specific ts file every type that you want to reference in that file.

Comment: Do you think this is the same type of error I am having here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162638/navigator-object-error-with-typescript-angular-2 ?

Comment: nah, different problem. will comment there.

Comment: Go to http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/ and click on link Add this plugin to your app's module The example given is for Camera. Replace Camera with StausBar. Usually docs help more