# Navigator and window type error with TypeScript and Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to use ng2-translate in my Ionic 2 app, with:

```
this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
            if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
                if (navigator.globalization) {
                    navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function (language) {
```

but I get this error

```
Typescript Error
Property 'globalization' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
src/app/app.component.ts
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    if (navigator.globalization) {
```

And I have the same type of error with `window.cordova`in this line of code:

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova') && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
```

Should I declare navigator type or something ?

Comment: Try: `npm install @types/cordova --save-dev`, might help...

Comment: no I still have the error

Answer (score 0):

You're missing Typescript typing information for that navigator object. Basically, the error you're seeing is the Typescript compiler saying that, based on the type definitions you have supplied so far, there is no information stating that the `navigator` object has a `globalization` property.

The solution is to add the typing information for that navigator object.

I'm honestly not sure which package contains those type definitions, but from Typescript v2 (or v2.1... can't remember which), npm stores type definitions for Typescript libraries under the @types namespace.

So, you want to

```
npm install --save-dev @types/<some package>
```

to add the type definitions into your project.

I'd take a guess at starting with:

```
@npm install --save-dev @types/cordova-ionic
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I don't understand Typescript typing very well yet. And I don't see how this facilitate coding by the way...not as flexible as plain javascript.
Anyway, with `npm install --save-dev @types/cordova-ionic` I still get the same error, is there any database where to find which package contains the typings for navigator.globalization, window.cordova, navigator.userLanguage ?

Comment: I think I need to add Ionic Native Globalization plugin first.